# useEffect with props as dependency not executed when parent state changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have two separate components **Audit** and **Reports** that both render **CommonDataTable** component as a child. **CommonDataTable's** useEffect hook with props.data in dependency array is being run correctly when used inside Reports, but is not run when used in Audit even though they both pass their state as props into **CommonDataTable**

Audit component:

```
function Audit(props: any) {

  const [tableData, setTableData] = React.useState([]);
  const [totalRecords, setTotalRecords] = React.useState(0);
  
  //fetch data and set to state
  const { refetch } = useQuery(GET_AUDIT_DATA, {
    variables: { inputAuditData: { perPage: perPage, page: currentPage,  filterText: "", sortBy: "", sortOrder: "" } },
    onCompleted: (data: any) => {
      console.log("refetch compmleted")
      setTableData(data.records) 
      setTotalRecords(data.totalCount)
    }
  });

  // refetch for data dictionary on data table parameter change
  const refreshData = async ( perPage: number, currentPage: number, filterText:"", sortBy: string, sortOrder: string) => {
      await refetch({
        inputAuditData: { perPage: perPage, page: currentPage, filterText: filterText, sortBy: sortBy, sortOrder: sortOrder }
      })
  }

  return (
    <>
      {console.log("Audit tableData", tableData)}
      <CommonDataTable 
        data={tableData} 
        totalNoRows={totalRecords} 
        refreshData={refreshData} 
      />
      </>
  )
}
```

Reports component

```
function Reports(props: any) {
  const [tableData, setTableData] = React.useState([]);
  const [totalRecords, setTotalRecords] = React.useState(0);

  // fetch report data and set the redux store
  const { refetch } = useQuery(GET_REPORTS_DATA, {
    variables: { inputDataDictionary: { modelID: parseInt(modelId), variables: "", perPage: perPage, page: currentPage, filterText: "", sortBy: "", sortOrder: "" }},
    onCompleted: (data: any) => {
      console.log("refetch compmleted")
      props.initModelData(data) //set data to redux store
      setTotalRecords(data.totalCount) 
    }
  });

  // refetch for reports data on data table parameter change
  const refreshData = async (perPage: number, currentPage: number, filterText: string, sortBy: string, sortOrder: string ) => {
    sortBy = sortBy === 'localizedType' ? 'type' : sortBy
    await refetch({
      inputDataDictionary: { modelID: parseInt(modelId), variables: "", perPage: perPage, page: currentPage, filterText: "", sortBy: sortBy, sortOrder: sortOrder }
      })
  }

  // react hook watches change in redux store and sets state using setTableData()
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTableData(props.modelData)
  }, [props.modelData]);
  
  return (
    <>
      {console.log("Reports tableData", tableData)}
      <CommonDataTable 
        data={tableData} 
        totalNoRows={totalRecords} 
        refreshData={refreshData} 
        />
   </>    
  )
}
```

CommonDataTable component:

```
export default function CommonDataTable(props: any) {
  const [tableData, setTableData] = React.useState([]);

  // should execute to update table data when the data is being refreshed
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("CD setTableData in useEffect ******* ")
    setTableData(props.data)
  }, [props.data]);

  return (
      {console.log("CD tableData", tableData)}
      <DataTable
        data={tableData}
      />
  )
}
```

As you can see Audit component after fetching the data sets it directly to state using setTableData(). But Reports component after fetching it sets data to redux store and then uses useEffect hook to watch redux store changes and then set data using setTableData() from there. Both components pass tableData as props into CommonDataTable component.

Any ideas why useEffect hook in child CommonDataTable component not being run when setTableData updates state in the parent component Audit?

Comment: why do you use useEffect and useState in CommonDataTable? CommonDataTable is a child component and will re-render.

Comment: I believe useEffect's dependencies uses a shallow comparison to detect changes, so in order for it to detect changes within an array or object, you can JSON.stringify the dependency, so it will detect all changes. That being said, in your case you shouldn't be using useEffect to set a state, you should just use the data in redux directly, as that will trigger a re-render when changed.